# Accessing an external php file in vue.js with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using axios inside a vue component and trying to call an "external" php file. I have my src folder. Inside that are my components. My root is court. I have a folder named ajax where all of my php server side pages live. From my component I am trying to call a page from the ajax folder but don't know how to get to it.

`Court\ 
  ajax\
    results.php
  src\
    components\
       search.vue`

So in search.vue i have an axios call
`axios.get('ajax/results.php',.....`

But it never reaches that page. I am also using the built in server and when I try `http://localhost:8080/court/ajax/results.php` it can't find that page. How do I call results.php?

Comment: If the built-in server you're talking about is webpack-dev-server or something similar, then it's not going to work. You need to serve your PHP from a separate, real server that can run PHP. Make sure your php files can be accessed directly from the browser before you even start debugging the Vue app.

Comment: I second @mzgajner, get access to your php file/output first and then we can look at helping.